# How to stop 'iCloud Download' column from reappearing

Tags: itunes

I don't want the iCloud Download column in iTunes; it really does nothing for me. Whenever I turn it off, it is there next time I open iTunes. This is so frustrating - is there any way to turn it off for good?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Only Music Available Offline" option in the [View] menu. Do this not only for Music, but also for Movies and TV Shows (switch to these views from the [view] menu also. THEN remove the iCloud Download column. It should remain gone now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems not.

Best I can find it to just grab the column header & drag it as far to the right as it will go.
At least it will stay there.